# Ubuntu guest can't see Vagrantfile in Window's host project directory

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I just installed Vagrant 1.4.3 on Windows 7 64-bit and created an Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy) box using the following:

> vagrant box add saucy64-20140226 http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/saucy/20140226/saucy-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
>
> vagrant init saucy64-20140226

After doing:

> vagrant up

I SSH'ed to the vagrant box using Putty.  Up to this point is fine, but when I do:

$ ls

in the /vagrant directory (on the Guest), I do not see my 'Vagrantfile' or any other files from the Host machine.

Also, any files created in the Guest's /vagrant directory do not show up in the Host's synced directory.

I noticed the following when the box/vm was starting up:

> [default] The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed
> version of VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases
> it can prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If
> you see shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions
> within the virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have
> installed on your host and reload your VM.

Answer (score 0):

After researching a little more, found that the following solves the issue:

https://github.com/dotless-de/vagrant-vbguest

Here's a more detailed post:

http://kvz.io/blog/2013/01/16/vagrant-tip-keep-virtualbox-guest-additions-in-sync/

Thanks very much to the folks who created the 'vagrant-vbguest' Vagrant plugin!!!